# datediff(MINUTE,[End Time],[Start Time])

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I run query below:

```
select datediff(MINUTE,[End Time],[Start Time]) 
from [LINKEDAF].[PRD Project].[Data].[EFAN1]
```

it gives error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I tried couple things with cast and convert but the same issue:

```
select datediff(MINUTE,convert(varchar(24),[End Time],120),convert(varchar(24),[End Time],120)) 
from [LINKEDAF].[PRD Project].[Data].[EFAN1]

select datediff(MINUTE,cast([End Time] as datetime),cast([End Time] as datetime)) 
from [LINKEDAF].[PRD Project].[Data].[EFAN1]
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What is Data type of `[End Time]`and `[Start Time]` and what kind of data is present int it

Comment: End Time                     Start Time 
09/09/2016 10:51:46    09/09/2016 10:50:38 
09/09/2016 10:51:46    09/09/2016 10:50:38 
09/09/2016 10:49:21    09/09/2016 10:44:58

Comment: Hi Tony, please provide some examples with a day over 12. These values might me dd/mm or mm/dd.

Comment: format is: 09/09/2016 10:51:46

Comment: and data type of columns?

Comment: it looks like string

Comment: Tony, `09/09/2016` can be DD/MM/YYYY as well as MM/DD/YYYY ...

Comment: it's DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Tony, you **know**, or you **think**?

Comment: I know it's string and format is DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 0):

To do datediff, you have to have 2 date or datetime-values. to convert strings to date or datetime, you should use

```
CONVERT(date[time], 'yourdata', FORMAT)
```

for the format have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are using this

```
convert(varchar(24),[End Time],120)
```

While the format `120` means this: *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)*

In comments you state, that the actual format is `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`

So you might try with `131` or try to split your value with `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` and cast date with `103` and time with `108`. Find [Details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

And furthermore you want to convert to `datetime`, so you should use

```
convert(datetime,[End Time],131)
```

### UPDATE Example

Try like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourValues VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('09/09/2016 10:51:46'),('09/09/2016 10:50:38'),('09/09/2016 10:51:46')
                      ,('09/09/2016 10:50:38'),('09/09/2016 10:49:21'),('09/09/2016 10:44:58');

--This works
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,YourValues,131)
FROM @tbl

--And this too
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(YourValues,10),103)+CONVERT(DATETIME,RIGHT(YourValues,8),108)
FROM @tbl
```

If this does not help you, you tell us what you think you see, but not what is really there...

Comment: this one doesn't work:   select datediff(MINUTE,convert(datetime,[End Time],131), convert(datetime,[Start Time],131) ) from [LINKEDAF].[PRD Project].[Data].[EFAN1]  what would be complete query with LEFT() and RIGHT()

Comment: this one doesn't work: select convert(datetime,right([End Time],108)+left([End Time],103)) from [LINKEDAF].[PRD Project].[Data].[EFAN1]

Comment: Shnugo, doesn't make sense why but doesn't work too: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([End Time],10),103)+CONVERT(DATETIME,RIGHT([End Time],8),108)
FROM [LINKEDAF].[PRD Project].[Data].[EFAN1]

Comment: Hi @Tony, if you've got an error, you should try to go small steps... In stead of your full select, try nothing more than `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,[End Time],131)  FROM [LINKEDAF].[PRD Project].[Data].[EFAN1]`. Same with `[Start Time]`... If this does not lead to a list of valid dates, select these columns *plainly* and look at the values carefully. Sometimes there are values like `31/06/2016` which simply does not exist... or there are other invalid values... There might be anything within a string column... Check the source values!

Answer (score 0):

At first try to use [ISDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) on that values

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.
>
> ISDATE returns 0 if the expression is a datetime2 value.

Take a look what will this query return:

```
SELECT  [End Time],
        [Start Time] 
FROM [LINKEDAF].[PRD Project].[Data].[EFAN1]
WHERE ISDATE([End Time]) = 0 OR ISDATE([Start Time]) = 0
```

After that post results, maybe there are some dates that SQL cannot parse properly, or there are `datetime2` format.

If I use `varchar` with values you provide - I get results:

```
;WITH YourTable AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('09/09/2016 10:51:46', '09/09/2016 10:50:38'),
('09/09/2016 10:49:21', '09/09/2016 10:44:58')
) as t([Start Time], [End Time])
)

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[Start Time],[End Time])
FROM YourTable
```

Gives:

```
-1
-5
```

Comment: Have you checked ISDATE?

Comment: I tested it and it gave some data but I didn't go further since I got date format columns from different table but thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: Yea, thanks with orig date format column datediff work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  SQL Server 2012 or higher version,Try with the below script.

```
SELECT datediff(MINUTE,cast([EndTime] as datetime),cast([StartTime] as datetime)) 
FROM YourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,[EndTime]) IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,[StartTime])  IS NOT NULL
```

here is one sample scenario.

[image]